# JQuery input val doesn't reflect change when the page is auto refresh

Tags: php, jquery

I am using combination of php and jQuery to show input value of dynamic content. My page auto background refresh every few minutes but I can't seems to get working when the value is changed.

```
<div> Odds: </div> //here the odd changes every mins.. echo $bet_option_info['bet_option_odd'];
<div id="show">Show value: </div>
<input id="stake-input"> 


<?php $odd = $bet_option_info['bet_option_odd'];?>

jQuery(body).ready(function() {
jQuery("body").keyup('#stake-input', function() {
  var odd = '<?php echo $odd; ?>';
  var inputs = Number(jQuery("#stake-input").val().trim());
  var result = (odd * inputs);
    jQuery('#show').val("" + result.toFixed(2));
 });
});
```

So basically odd changes when the page is auto refreshed. But it's just that val calculation doesn't change. For eg.. if the ODD is 2 and input value is 5. It will show 10 (odd x stake). And after 1 minute, ODD became 3 after the page is refreshed. Here again if I input, it should be 15 (3 odd X 5 input) but it only reflects the original value of 2. The odd is changing fine.

Help is apprecaited

Comment: how are you changing `$odd` value? ajax? page reload?

Comment: Try `var odd = <?php echo $odd; ?>;` (without the quotes making it a string) ;)

Comment: @kuromoka The odds are changing by jQuery page reload.

Comment: @Jay Bro can you show `jQuery page reload` part?

Comment: @kuromoka here is jQuery..   jQuery(body).ready(function(){
        jQuery.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
event.preventDefault();
        setInterval(function () {
            jQuery('#livemd').load(' #livemd');
        }, 50000);      
    });

Comment: sorry for many questions. what is `#livemd` ?

Comment: @kuromoka : No problem asking. Appreciate your help in trying to figure out.. #livemd is the division that reload the Odds file that fetch data from database

Comment: as far as I heard your comments, maybe odd value needs to refer from `#livemd`.

Comment: @kuromoka The thing is odds get updated but it's just that input val fails to catch the changed value in odds. Not sure why it shouldn't be working.

Comment: did you confirm `var odd` is 3 truly after 1 minute? please show me `console.log(odd);` of 1 minute later value.

Comment: @JayBro Check your browser console for errors. Hint: `jQuery(body)`?